# Get button clicks, input text from google sheets inside webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have an android application which has a google form inside a webview. It has three input boxes(Name, address and phone number), and a button. I need this input values and the button click event for further processing within the app. Is there any way by which I can do this?

The fragment that contains the google sheet:

```
public class Register extends Fragment {


public Register() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("my google sheet");

    return view;
}
}
```

The XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener for each button and get event using reflection:

```
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
{
  public void performClick()
  {
    // Deal with a click on the OK button
  }
}, "google_sheet_button");
```

Then in the HTML, call it directly from the button tag:

```
<button type="button" onclick="google_sheet_button.performClick();">google Sheet Save</button>
```